# Adding array to array with JSON_MODIFY

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, t-sql, sql-server-2016

```
DECLARE @JSON_CurrentArray NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{"Some List":
[{"Name":"Item1","Id":"2"},{"Name":"Item2","Id":"3"}]}';
DECLARE @JSON_TopLevel NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{"OverAll":[{"Product Section":[]}]}';
SET @JSON_TopLevel = JSON_MODIFY(@JSON_TopLevel, 'append $."Overall"."Product Selection"', JSON_QUERY(@JSON_CurrentArray));
SELECT @JSON_TopLevel;
```

Ive been trying to stick CurrentArray into TopLevel,

Tried some crazy append/lax/strict combinations... but im new to JSON Manipulation and am almost at 'liquid brain stage' over this item.
I also thought about adding a blank array, but to no avail (i might be doing that wrong also)

Right now im code blind, so, If you can somehow inject one array into another... #foreverindebted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want something like this:

```
DECLARE @JSON_CurrentArray NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{"Some List":
[{"Name":"Item1","Id":"2"},{"Name":"Item2","Id":"3"}]}';
DECLARE @JSON_TopLevel NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{"OverAll":[{"Product Section":[]}]}';
SET @JSON_TopLevel = JSON_MODIFY(@JSON_TopLevel, 'append $."OverAll"[0]."Product Section"', JSON_QUERY(@JSON_CurrentArray));
SELECT @JSON_TopLevel;
```

**[DBFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a162cde01942ef73265c959ce27cfbfd)**

Result:

> {"OverAll":[{"Product Section":[{"Some List": [{"Name":"Item1","Id":"2"},{"Name":"Item2","Id":"3"}]}]}]}

To check if your path is correct you could use [`JSON_QUERY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql) and `strict` mode:

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(@JSON_TopLevel, 'strict $."OverAll"."Product Section"')
--Msg 13608 Level 16 State 5 Line 7
--Property cannot be found on the specified JSON path.

-- vs
SELECT JSON_QUERY(@JSON_TopLevel, 'strict $."OverAll"[0]."Product Section"')
-- []
```

Comment: Sorry about the product selection/section. Can't use my actual data. I'll be trying this in about an hour. But so I understand correctly... I'm building a JSON object with various depth. Would overall always have the position[0] or would I need to declare other attributes' position down the line. Assume that all of my multiple records with similar names are leaves and never need to be added to. I have a parent child tree, unique names, and I'm filling up TopLevel with data from the tree (to serve, not store/edit)